# Get list of values from multiple tabs and copy to a column in another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a script from searches on stackoverflow and come up with this so far:

```
function collectData(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var target = ss.getSheetByName("Export");

for ( i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){  
var names = sheets[i].getRange("B1").getValue();    

Logger.log(names);

 }
}
```

This is working as expected but I am trying to then list the values in another sheet. I've tried copyTo and setValues and push to send the list of values to a specific sheet but keep getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set values in some range of a spreadsheet, you need to arrange them in a double array. A row is `[[x, y, z]]`, a column is `[[x], [y], [z]]`. Since you want a column, the logic would be

```
var names = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){  
  names.push([sheets[i].getRange("B1").getValue()]); 
}
target.getRange(1, 1, names.length, 1).setValues(names);
```

Reference: [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)).

To make a row instead, some square brackets get moved around:

```
var names = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){  
  names.push(sheets[i].getRange("B1").getValue()); 
}
target.getRange(1, 1, 1, names.length).setValues([names]);
```

Comment: I love your brain soup....ok that sounds weird but you know what I mean....add comma haha!